# html2canvas absolute elements get stacked at the top

Tags: javascript, html2canvas

Trying to use [html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) with some absolute position divs created with [Gridstack](http://troolee.github.io/gridstack.js/).

Everything works great with Gridstack, but when I implement html2canvas, every div, or Gridstack item, gets sucked up to the top and stacked upon each other. If I turn of Gridstack and just use Bootstrap or something that doesn't applt `position:absolute` to each element it works fine.

Is there something I'm missing, or does html2canvas just not support absolute positioned elements?

Comment: what exactly you are trying to do with html2canvas ? I dont think it is somehow related to UI..

Comment: Just simply grab what's in the division and create an image. Has nothing to do with UI. Gridstack is just being used to position stuff

Comment: What exactly you mean by **gets sucked up to the top and stacked upon each other** ?

Comment: Each element is at the top of the rendered image, on top of each other. Almost like the css has been set to top:0px on each div

Comment: Need to see working example, can not help you without that..